# Implement INotifyDataErrorInfo in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I like how works INotifyDataErrorInfo in Silverlight.

But I realized that it does not exist in WPF. Are there another ways to implement validation in WPF? I prefer not to use DataAnotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IDataErrorInfo` wich is the same

Here a demo
http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

Answer (score 7):

You could wait for [WPF 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx) which will finally have support for INotifyDataErrorInfo.

Comment: do you know when is going to release?

Comment: @DarfZon there is no release date yet, but most are guessing sometime later this year, before the Windows 8 release.